# vcpkg manifest install system wide

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, lib, vcpkg

Just tried [Vcpkg Manifest](https://vcpkg.io/en/docs/users/manifests.html) on my cmake project and it is cool, with exceptions however.

My project depends on opencv and it takes a long time for vcpkg to install opencv. So I realized I don't want vcpkg downloawding/installing opencv every time I clone the project in a different folder.

Is it possible to use Vcpkg Manifest but make it install libraries system wide instead of locally to the project?

Or at least not inside the build directory, so will be possible to reuse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't install libraries system-wide in manifest mode.
But binaries are cached so that if you use a library in multiple projects, you don't have to build it from scratch.
https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/binarycaching.md

Answer (score 0):

I abused vcpkg's `--x-install-root` to achieve similar results as manifest mode.

> --x-install-root=         (Experimental) Specify the install root directory

Under your project folder, you can install this project's dependencies into a system global directory by using this parameter, so that all projects can share the installed packages system wide. For example, in my case, I installed all packages into `$VCPKG_ROOT/installed` directory like this:

```
vcpkg install --x-install-root=$VCPKG_ROOT/installed
```

You can even use `vcpkg list` anywhere if you (ab)use it this way.